# Vaadin 14 without Maven and without Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jetty, maven-2

I would like to create a Vaadin 14 application without using Maven or Spring Boot. Just a plain Java application with an embedded Jetty server. This was possible in the past. Is it still possible somehow?

Old code with Vaadin 6.x and Jetty:

```
private static void initServer(Settings settings) throws Exception, InterruptedException {
    httpPort = settings.getInt("webapp.port", 8888);
    final Server server = new Server(httpPort);
    final WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
    webapp.setContextPath("/");
    webapp.setResourceBase("WebContent");
    webapp.setClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
    server.setHandler(webapp);
    server.start();
    server.join();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible, you have a metric buttload of extra work to do by not using a build tool (any java build tool. eg: maven, gradle, ant+ivy, leiningen, grape, buildr, bazel, etc ...), but it is possible.

You will have many jars to manage, not just within Jetty, but also it's dependencies outside of Jetty (like the various spec api jars).

Then you'll have some changes to make for your embedded jetty usage.

The changes you'll need to make depend on the version of Jetty you intend to use.

- Jetty 9.x (Servlet 3.1 / Java EE 7) - https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/tree/jetty-9.4.x/examples/embedded
- Jetty 10.x (Servlet 4.0 / Jakarta EE 8) - https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/tree/jetty-10.0.x/demos/embedded
- Jetty 11.x (Servlet 5.0 / Jakarta EE 9) https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/tree/jetty-11.0.x/demos/embedded

You are going from Jetty 6.x, which was for Servlet 2.1 on Java EE 4.
Since then there's been a tremendous amount of changes in the various EE specs, the HTTP specs, and even Java JVM itself that has caused changes down to Jetty.

Answer (score 0):

Vaadin itself offers [several different example projects](https://vaadin.com/start#tech-stack-examples) of Vaadin 14 with/without Spring and different build tools. Gradle is often used as an alternative to Maven and the plain Java style can be found in an example without any CDI.